# Is DNX missing in VS Community

Tags: .net, dnx, asp.net5

I'm trying to do a test deployment that's cross platform by following a tutorial. The Tutorial has the option to choose 'Target DNX version' but on my computer for my .Net Core project, I only have one option ".NetCoreApp..." - See image

[image]

I'm using VS2015 Community. I installed .Net core & chose to create a project type of "ASP.NET Core Web App". What am I missing, please? Is it b/c I'm using Community?

R

---

Update! I was able to publish for osx using...

dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp1.0 --runtime osx.10.11-x64

which i found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-publish

So now my question is, how to execute this on the mac. I'm new to Macs & saw launching the exe didn't work. It tried to launch Parallel.

In windows I published content in folder 'osx.10.11-x64' as in screen shot. I copied the folder to my mac and want to execute the web app.

Anyone know?

### [image]

Comment: Throw away that tutorial as it is out-of-date. Official documentation is at https://docs.asp.net The rule of thumb is that anything earlier than June 2016 is out-of-date.

Comment: @LexLi Here's what I'm doing. See something wrong? https://youtu.be/QI1dyqgjA6I

Comment: If you check the index, https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/index.html, then it is clearly that at this moment Microsoft only expects VS to work with a limited set of scenarios, while you should use `dotnet publish` for others. Play with each tutorials and also report issues back to Microsoft, https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues

Answer (score 2):

You can't select that option, because DNX is now obsolete. I presume you're looking at an out-of-date tutorial

You can read more here: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx

Here's a quote:

> DNX and DNVM have been replaced by the new .NET CLI. See:
>
> http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/
>
> http://github.com/dotnet/cli

There's a migration guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migrating-from-dnx

Comment: I just want to publish my .Net Core app I wrote on Windows so I can test run it on my mac. When I published, it created a bunch of DLLs which only works on Windows. Can you point me to steps do this please?

Comment: I think your project is using the .NET Framework, not .NET Core, and that's why you're getting DLLs.  If you create a new project, you'll see there's two project types: 1. Asp.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core) and 2. ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Framework).  Try creating a new project using the .NET core template - then copy & paste your code into that.  You might find that certain assemblies are not compatible, because not all existing assemblies have been recreated for .NET Core yet (and some never will be).

Comment: @ Delosdos I did. Here's a video of me doing it. Let me know if you see anything off. https://youtu.be/QI1dyqgjA6I

Comment: @myfunnyfella OK, I see what you're trying to do.  I haven't tried it myself, but this might be of use to you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBk4a0mjo0I&feature=youtu.be&t=42m47s

Comment: @ Delosdos thanks. He is doing doing what I want to do but doesn't show how he set it up. Also he has DNX reference that others just told me are obsolete.

I simply want the steps to set up my environment so I can deploy, copy results to a MAC & see it run. Let me know if you find anything else please. 

I'll keep looking. I can't believe this is such a hassle. I thought deploying  for osx would be easy given all the portability talk.